# Iterating over results, sorted by a m2m

Tags: django, django-models

My data model is simple:

```
class Neighborhood(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    slug = models.SlugField()

class Location(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    alt_name = models.CharField()
    neighborhoods = models.ManyToManyField(Neighborhood)
```

I would like to supply a page on my site that lists all locations by their neighborhood (s). If it were singular, I think `{% regroup %}` with a `{% ifchanged %}` applied to the neighborhood name would be all that I need, but in my case, having it be a m2m, I'm not sure how do this. A location may have multiple neighborhoods, and so I would like them to be redundantly displayed under each matching neighborhood.

I'm also aware of `FOO_set` but that's per Object; I want to load the entire data set.

The final result (in the template) should be something like:

```
Alameda
    Crazy Thai
Castro
    Kellys Burgers
    Pizza Orgasmica
Filmore
    Kellys Burgers
    Some Jazz Bar
Mission
    Crazy Thai
    Elixir
...
```

The template syntax would (ideally?) look something like:

```
{% for neighborhood in neighborhood_list %}
    {% ifchanged %}{{ neighborhood.name }}{% endifchanged %}
    {% for location in neighborhood.restaurants.all %}
        {{ location.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what prevents you from putting a m2m field pointing to companies in to your neighbourhood type?

Comment: I could, but Location already has neighborhood assigned. I should be able to grab the reverse relation. I think something like deafaultdict will help me, but im getting confused...

Comment: unless I misunderstood the question, I think, you can Location.objects.order_by('neighborhoods__name')

Comment: that would order neighborhoods within each object, but not globally.

Comment: oh, it just occurred to me. you can use the 'through' model. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just do it the expensive way and cache the result over scratching my head. Your template example would work fine until performance becomes an issue in generating that one page per X cache timeout.

You could do it in python as well if the result set is small enough:

```
# untested code - don't have your models
from collections import defaultdict

results = defaultdict(list)
for location_m2m in Location.neighborhoods.through.objects.all() \ # line wrap
        .select_related('neighborhood', 'location', 'location__company__name'):

    if location_m2m.location not in results[location_m2m.neighborhood]:
        results[location_m2m.neighborhood].append(location_m2m.location)

# sort now unique locations per neighborhood
map(lambda x: x.sort(key=lambda x: x.location.company.name), results.values())

# sort neighborhoods by name
sorted_results = sorted(results.items(), key=lambda x:x[0].name)
```

Comment: Agh. Perfect. I'm going to go over this and the other option and weight them. I definetaly don't like wasting time scratching my head--so I'll see if I can get this down now. It's worth it. Thanks again for an example relevant to my models.

Comment: This is working nicely for me. I now have the list displaying as I would like. Im not sorting by ``company.name`` however, so I just took that out. This breaks sorting. The ``Location`` has a local field, ``alt_name`` but upon replacing company.name instances with it, i get errors. Not sure why. The query is right however--and that feels /awesome/.

Comment: Hey hey, cool beans! What's the error? Can you re-post what you're trying?

Comment: http://dpaste.com/640425/ With each reload of the page, the order seems to display in random order.

Comment: Ok, I'm spotting an error: try changing the final sort line to `key=lambda x:x[0].id` - you need to sort the neighborhoods by /something/. In my testing, if you try to sort a queryset without args, it changes.

Comment: ahh! i was trying ``key=lambda x:x.name`` which now obviously makes no sense. Thank you.

Comment: That was my bad - I wrote that :P

Answer (score 1):

create another model that would define your m2m relationship:

`class ThroughModel(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location')
    neighborhood = models.ForeignKey('Neighborhood')`

and use it as the `through` model for your m2m field:

`class Location(models.Model):
    ...
    neighborhoods = models.ManyToManyField(Neighborhood, through='ThroughModel')`

Then you can get all your neighbourhoods sorted:

`ThroughModel.objects.select_related().order_by('neighborhood__name')`

**This is untested.**

Or, if you cannot change the database, just do a raw SQL join.

Comment: Can't I just do something in a view? It seems sort of weird to me to create another table just to get a query a want. I do see the advantage in this, perhaps in a new project but not this one. If this were an individual Neighborhood, no problem. It would be very simular to how we list blog posts matching a particular category. Something like `Location.objects.filter(neighborhoods__slug = slug)`. What I want to do, I believe, is iterate over every location object on a single page / dictionary. Thats why I got thinking maybe `collections.defaultdict` would be the key (heh).

Comment: an intermediate table is created anyway, you just do not see it in django code, but it is in the database. there is no difference internally between my through model and the default m2m implementation.

Comment: Can I just retroactively add the through() to my model field or can South help me out?

Comment: I think it is better to use South if you have data in your production database.

Comment: but if you can simply use ``.through()`` as the other answer demonstrates, why would i go out of the way to manually create this through tabel?

Comment: it is not "through()" it is "through" without parentheses. it is an undocumented property. but yes you can use that.